# Jquery to disable a group of radio buttons if one of them is selected?

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I need help writing Jquery to disable a group of radio button when one is selected?

1) If radio button with value="One1" is selected the other radio buttons with "One2" and "One3" are disabled. Selecting "Bk1" will enable them again.

2) If radio button with value="One2" is selected the other radio buttons with "One1" and "One3" are disabled. Selecting "Bk2" will enable them again.

3) If radio button with value="One3" is selected the other radio buttons with "One1" and "One2" are disabled. Selecting "Bk3" will enable them again.

```
<input name="session1" class="Session" type="radio" value="Bk1">Break Out
<input name="session1" class="Session" type="radio" value="One1">One-on-One Consulting 


<input name="session2" class="Session" type="radio" value="Bk2">Break Out
<input name="session2" class="Session" type="radio" value="One2">One-on-One Consulting 


<input name="session3" class="Session" type="radio" value="Bk3">Break Out
<input name="session3" class="Session" type="radio" value="One3">One-on-One Consulting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add some classes to your HTML markup, but is this what you're looking for ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsKZq/))?

```
<div>
    <input name="session1" class="Session breakout" type="radio" value="Bk1">Break Out
    <input name="session1" class="Session consulting" type="radio" value="One1">One-on-One Consulting
</div>
<div>
    <input name="session2" class="Session breakout" type="radio" value="Bk2">Break Out
    <input name="session2" class="Session consulting" type="radio" value="One2">One-on-One Consulting
</div>
<div>
    <input name="session3" class="Session breakout" type="radio" value="Bk3">Break Out
    <input name="session3" class="Session consulting" type="radio" value="One3">One-on-One Consulting
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.consulting').click(function(){
        $('.Session[name!="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').attr('disabled', '');
    });

    $('.breakout').click(function(){
       $('.Session').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.Session').click(function(){
   if(this.value == 'One1' && this.checked){
       console.log($('input[value=One2], input[value=One3'));
        $('input[value=One2], input[value=One3]').prop('disabled', true);
   }
   else if(this.value == 'One2' && this.checked){
        $('input[value=One1], input[value=One3]').prop('disabled', true);
   }
   else if(this.value == 'One3' && this.checked){
        $('input[value=One1], input[value=One2]').prop('disabled', true);   
   }
   else{
      $('.Session').not(this).prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PAD24/)**